# Cheapest sink in Azure Data Factory Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm using Azure Data Factory for reading data from a Data Lake and storing the filtered data into Cosmos DB (Sql Api) in one container. I'm using Integration Runtime - Memory Optimized, 4 (+4 Driver Cores) in ADF and Autoscale 20,000 RU/s in Cosmos DB. The ADF pipeline takes ~20 min to complete the triggered run. I'm planning to run ADF pipeline once every day. On checking the monthly cost associated with ADF and Cosmos DB, I see that combined cost of ADF and Cosmos DB is ~$150. (ADF cost: ~70$ Cosmos DB: ~$70). Is there an alternate sink that I could use instead of Cosmos DB to reduce the cost. 
Note: I need to use a sink where I can query.

Here is the time spent in sink transformation: [image] [image]

Comment: Can you open the ADF data flow monitoring view to see where most of that 30 mins in being spent? Click on the Sink transformation in the monitoring graph and look at the right-hand panel. It will show you the number of mins/secs spent writing to CosmosDB.

To lower that number, provide more RUs.

But if most of the time is spent inside your transformation stages, then increase the number of cores from 8 to 16 or 32.

Lastly, you can reduce your spend in ADF by using Compute Optimized instead of memory optimized. But that will increase the time spent inside the transformation stages. HTH!

Comment: Thank you! Time spent in Sink Transformation is 14 min (Please see image in the above question).

Comment: Your data flow is only spending about 2 mins in Spark w/transformation stages. The bulk of the time is CosmosDB I/O. If you are OK with your pipeline taking a little longer to complete, you can switch to a Compute Optimized Azure IR and it should lower your ADF costs.

Answer (score 0):

Why use autoscale? ADF understands 429's so can apply back pressure and copy the data at a minimum 400 RU/s

Comment: Please help me understand. What do you mean by apply back pressure? When I kept Manual 400 RU /s, I was getting a large number of throttling requests. That's why I used Autoscale.

Comment: Well not back pressure per-se. ADF implements our bulk executor library. That library is designed to saturate your provisioned throughput as much as possible. So if you see any throttling requests, you can ignore them. they are basically informational, our bulk executor library is handling this internally.

Comment: In the ADF data flow Sink transformation, there is a property called "Write throughput budget". There you can set the number of RUs to dedicate to the bulk ingestion job.

Comment: @MarkBrown Could you please let me know what do you mean by ignoring throttling requests? Is it fine to have throttling requests during pipeline run?

Comment: @MarkKromer Thank you! So, in Cosmos DB can I set Throughput to 400 RU/s (Manual) and in ADF Sink Settings, Throughput to 400 RU/s? What should I set as Write throughput budget? Should it be 400 RU/s? Please let me know.

Comment: You can set the RUs in the Throuphput setting in the Sink and ADF will use that throughput just for that job. Write throughput budget is optional if you need to specify RUs just for the Spark bulk ingest job.